# Regex code to identify Keyword followed by complex pattern (from variable human inputs)

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am working on an NLP project with  data that requires some cleaning of PII. I have dates and names mostly taken care using spaCy NER, but I need to find instances of (case insensitive) Room followed by alphanumeric. I have something that works, but it is wildly ugly. I inherited a pattern from a coworker, but theirs missed many patterns, and will grab things like `The room was...` and miss `room  16b/16a/16c`. I am working python 3.X environment.

I am trying to learn and the best I can using regex101. While this pattern mostly works at finding the alpha-numeric pattern after room, desired, but will grab any word after room, this is undesired. `The room was cleaned` becomes `The room number cleaned`. I think the `\w?` is the cause of the undesired. I added the pattern after the `?\w? ?` and don't think it is efficient, nor easy to understand what is going on.

My pattern

```
(room|rm) ?(#|number|no.?)? ?\w? ?(\d+|[a-z0-9\-?\/\(\) ]{2,5})[a-z]?| (room?) ([0-9]+[a-z/]+)+| room? [a-z]?[0-9/]+
```

and examples

```
room (b7)
rm 2
rm no 4
room a12
Room 12
Roomd25
room D25
ROOM D25
ROOM C-11
room 17
room A4B
room 101
rm #17 
room 37/39
ROOM B-1
room C 29 from 
room C23/25/27
room 16b/18a/18b
Clean the room now _AVOID_
```

Comment: Regular expressions are often not the best solution for recognizing human inputs, because they don't always follow the rules you define in the pattern.

Comment: `?(#|number|no.?)? ?\w? ?` is a sequence of optional patterns. You might have wanted to match some of them only if others matched.

Comment: What kind of behavior are you expecting with entries like `room C23/25/27`? Do those room numbers need to be in separate capturing groups? And what's going on with `room C 29 from `? Should that be treated as invalid input?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew, I am still learning regex and will do some review on optional flagging before I ask any more questions.

@CAustin, we are replacing any and all room numbers that users input with the word redacted. I am very new at regex and am trying to learn on the fly. `room C 29 from` is just part of a larger corpus, were the word from would be ignored and the rest would be redacted. In the prior case we remove all three rooms as that provides a way for people to access Personally Identifying Information.

Comment: @ClaytonSummitt So we are colleagues, I also work in a Redaction team. The thing is, in order to write a working regex, you must come up with some concrete rules for a pattern. If you approach the problem by trying to accommodate to all examples you found, it is need to examine them and still try to deduce the verbal rules, e.g. "the match starts when the regex engine finds X, then it can match YZ, or just Z, but the whole part can be optional, then comes M, and then J K F, where K is optional". With the reasoning like that it is easier to come with a working pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Regex can be ugly for custom human inputs, since we are human we type differently stuff. If possible, try to clean the data before storing it.

Maybe makes everything lowercase, replace occurrences of `rm` with `room`. Remove any non alphanum character in the string. I'd surely do this before doing regex.

```
import re

def clean_data(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = text.replace("rm", "room")
    return re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', text)

pattern = r'\b(room|rm)\b\s*([#]?|number|no.?|[\w/()]*\w)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\b'

text = ['room b7', 'rm 2', 'not a room fsd', 'rm no 4', 'room a12', 'Room 12', 'Roomd25', 'room D25', 'ROOM D25', 'ROOM C11', 'room 17', 'room A4B', 'room 101', 'rm 17', 'room 37/39', 'ROOM B1', 'room C 29 from', 'room C23/25/27', 'room 16b/18a/18b', 'and other sentences that should be left intact like Clean the room now AVOID.']

ny_text = [clean_data(t) for t in text]


for t in ny_text:
    match = re.findall(pattern, t, re.IGNORECASE)
    if not match:
        continue
    room_alias = match[0][0]
    room_number = match[0][2]
    print(f"Found: {room_alias} {room_number}")
```

Comment: Our substitution method works fine allowing us to do less string manipulations, `re.sub(pattern, replace, text,0 , re.IGNORECASE)`. As I stated above, the issue is in the pattern matching component, I will see how the pattern you provide works out.